# useState inside useEffect not updating state

Tags: async-await, react-hooks

the state 'status' does not change values ​​and always keeps its initial value 'pending' and does not change value to 'on hold' knowing that I am sure that the request returns a result

```
const [_talentID, setTalentID] = useState(props.match.params.idTalent);
const [_jobID, setJobID] = useState(props.match.params.idJob);
const [status, setStatus] = useState('pending');

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getStatus() {
      await axios
        .get('api')
        .then(res => setStatus('on hold'))
    }
    getStatus();
    
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(status);
  }, [status]);
```

Comment: Need helps please !!!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot from network tab in the browser which shows the response?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is you're doing something else in your component that interferes. Can you show the entire component?

Also, does this work? (Basically just some refactoring, and using [this](https://gist.github.com/mariusbrataas/ffca05c210ec540b4fb9f4324c4f2e68) little hook.

```
function usePromiseMemo(callback, deps) {
  // Private states
  const [state, setState] = useState();
  const isMounted = useRef(true);

  // Register unmount
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!isMounted.current) isMounted.current = true;
    return () => {
      isMounted.current = false;
    };
  }, []);

  // Execute callback
  useEffect(() => {
    if (isMounted.current) {
      if (state !== undefined) setState(undefined);
      Promise.resolve()
        .then(() => callback())
        .then(r => {
          if (isMounted.current) setState(r);
        });
    }
  }, deps || []);

  // Return state
  return state;
}

// YOUR COMPONENT HERE
function MyComponent(props: any) {
  const [status, setStatus] = useState('pending');

  // Result of axios.get("api")
  const response = usePromiseMemo(
    () =>
      axios.get('api').then(res => {
        setStatus('on hold');
        return res;
      }),
    [setStatus]
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(status);
  }, [status]);

  return <div></div>;
}
```

Comment: I still get the same unexpected behavior. setStatus('on hold') 
not executed and the console always displays 'pending'. I tried to use useCallback
 and useMemo hook but always the same problem.

Comment: Gonna have to see more of your code (and network tab plz) to solve that one. Only thing that might cause this would be that the request fails. Did you try `.catch(() => setStatus("failed"))`?